# WP_Enqueue_Script Loads in Footer, Not Sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've have been working on creating a plugin for WordPress that adds a snippet of code to the sidebar when activated.

So far, the script works when the page is loaded, but it is displayed in the footer of the page instead of the sidebar.

What should I change to make the code display in the sidebar instead of the footer?

```
 /**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
   

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        
        
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }
 
      wp_enqueue_script( 'external-script'); 
      
     //echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
     echo $args['after_widget'];
       
        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_enqueue_script` loads js files either in the header or footer, never in a sidebar or anywhere else.

When a script is enqueued after the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action is fired it is always loaded in the footer.

From [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) documentation:

> As of Version 3.3, the function can be called mid-page (before the wp_footer() template tag) or using the wp_head action hook. This will place the script in the footer as if the $in_footer parameter was set to true.

If you want a script enqueued in the head, you'll have to attach your enqueue function to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'external-script');
});
```

This cannot be done in your `widget` method because that action has already fired by the time the widget is rendered.

If you want your script loaded in your sidebar, you'll have to manually output the `script` tag.

```
echo '<script src="' . esc_url($your_script_url) . '"></script>';
```